# Array to string conversion ERROR in php , mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Can some one give me a solution for this error. This the error that im getting

**Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\TomisStore\functions\add_to_cart.php on line 47
Array**

```
$newCart = new Cart();
$statement3 = $dbCon->prepare("SELECT MAX(cart_NO) FROM cart");
$statement3->execute();
 if ($statement3->rowCount() > 0) {
     $result2 = $statement3->fetch();
}     echo $result2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use var_dump($result2) or print_r($result2) and see what is in the fetch.

also you need to change your query to

```
"SELECT MAX(cart_NO) as cart_no FROM cart"
```

then you print the result to know how to access cart_no

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["cart_no"]=> string(1) "3" [0]=> string(1) "3" } }  this is the result i get when i use var_dump($result2). How can i access the value inside it. Please help me im bit new to PHP

Comment: then you coult simply acces $result[0]['cart_no']
by the way be careful because the variable $result2 could not exist if  `$statement3->rowCount() > 0` statement is false

Answer (score 2):

$result2 is an Array, not a string, echo expects a string

be Aware that $result2 is not within the same block it is defined

try var_dump($result2)

i assume, that you could echo $result2["MAX(cart_NO)"]

you could query SELECT MAX(cart_NO) as max_cart_no FROM cart

then you could echo $result2['max_cart_no'];

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["cart_no"]=> string(1) "3" [0]=> string(1) "3" } } this is the result i get when i use var_dump($result2). How can i access the value inside it. Please help me im bit new to PHP

Comment: see my answer: $result2['INDEX_VALUE'] where INDEX_VALUE is the Name of the selected tablefield. you can alter the Name of the table field as shown within the SQL via "as your_desired_Name". the var_dumps Shows the Indexes, for example $result2[0]["cart_no"] (2-dimensional Array)